# How do I show or trace what command a keyboard shortcut is mapped to in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

My keyboard shortcut for "Ctrl+D" is currently being overridden, but I don't know where or what command is overriding it. I'm guessing it is from a plugin.

How can I see what Ctrl+D is currently mapped to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) and enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`. Then enter Ctrl+D (or any keyboard shortcut) in the editor to see the associated command printed to the console.

Comment: For those that come across this later, you can use https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts to see what package a particular command is from. May not be an issue for you but if you have lots of plugins installed with lots of key bindings, it may be useful.